# One word for "change of requirements"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

In software or in Any Industry the change of requirements is often seen. Is there a particular single word  that can describe the "change of/in requirements". Apart form updation, editing, amendment etc.

Comment: Can you give an example usage? I can think of many words that mean or imply this in software but all depend on context.

Comment: You may have to take this to the Stack Overflow forum.  But since it is already here, let's take a crack at it. *Revision* is commonly used to denote a change in any specification.  Tracking such changes is called *Change Management* or *Version Control*.  Tracing individual specification points to a description or implementation is called *Traceability* (Requirements Traceability, Test Description Traceability, and so on).

An informal term that is used across the board to indicate changes (usually when the changes mainly consist of additions) to a spec is *Delta*.

Comment: You say "Apart from updation, editing, amendment etc." but that statement seems to exclude all words that could possibly work for you. Please [edit] your question to make it make sense. Add an example sentence at a minimum, and give a finite list of words that you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I think [respecification](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/respecification) as a general term may convey the meaning:

> - The act or process of respecifying; a change from a previous specification.

[Specification/Specifications](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/specification):

> - An explicit set of requirements to be satisfied by a material, product, or service.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=respecification&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crespecification%3B%2Cc0) shows an increasing  usage of the term since the 50s.

Source: http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/specification

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a single, definite word for what you're looking for. But having worked for a long time in the software industry , the single most used phrase I've seen, that describes the process of "change of requirements" is- "Change Request".

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_request), "change request" is defined as-

> A change request is a document containing a call for an adjustment of
>   a system; it is of great importance in the change management process
>
> A change request is declarative, i.e. it states what needs to be
>   accomplished, but leaves out how the change should be carried out.
>   Important elements of a change request are an ID, the customer (ID),
>   the deadline (if applicable), an indication whether the change is
>   required or optional, the change type (often chosen from a
>   domain-specific ontology) and a change abstract, which is a piece of
>   narrative (Keller, 2005). An example of a change request can be found
>   in Figure 1 on the right.

Another link [here](http://searchcio.techtarget.com/definition/change-request) describes "Change Request" as-

> A change request is a formal proposal for an alteration to some
>   product or system.
>
> In project management, a change request often arises when the client
>   wants an addition or alteration to the agreed-upon deliverables for a
>   project. Such a change may involve an additional feature or
>   customization or an extension of service, among other things. Because
>   change requests are beyond the scope of the agreement, they generally
>   mean that the client will have to pay for the extra resources required
>   to satisfy them.
>
> One of the more challenging aspects of change management is ensuring
>   that all details are sufficiently explicated and that all parties are
>   in agreement as to what is expected. Explicit and detailed
>   documentation makes it easier to identify when a change request must
>   be submitted.

I'm not sure about the accuracy of the phrase "Change Request" in other industries, but as far as the software industry is concerned, I think this term matches closely to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a word for this.

"[Respecification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/respecification)" is tempting, but only exists in Wiktionary with dubious etymology ("re" + "specification"). It does not have any entry in the OED or any other dictionary I could find. It also yields a mere ~85,000 Google results, which these days is not an indication of common usage. Personally, I am a software developer of ~20 years and I have never heard this word.

Because of its simplistic nature it *may* be understood by some readers, but I would certainly raise an eyebrow if I saw this word.

I cannot think of any single word that means "change of requirements". Generally I see that phrase used very often as is, e.g. "our robust software architecture can quickly be adapted to rapidly changing requirements".

There are, however, many adjectives that can be used to describe software / products / processes themselves that indicate their proficiency in *dealing* with changing requirements. Words such as "robust", "flexible", "agile", etc. are often used in this context.

There are also many other words and phrases that can describe the process of *requesting* or *stating* a change of requirements, e.g. "change order", "update" (I am aware you listed this), or simply "new requirements". However, without more context it is difficult to recommend a specific word or phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these words:

> changeover - a change from one system or situation to another.
>
> conversion - the process of changing or causing something to change from one form to another.
>
> transformation - a marked change in form, nature, or appearance

If you specify your requirement clearly, we can help you better.

**[Source](http://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/change)**